# How to find the right sending speed with UDP?

Tags: sockets, networking, udp

I want to transfer a large number of messages. The messages do not need to be reliable. UDP comes to mind as a protocol choice.

Latency is important as well. I do not want to suffer from TCP head-of-line blocking.

I'm concerned I might overload the network when I just start sending messages at maximum speed (e.g. `while (messagesRemaining != 0) Send(...);`). If I send more than some middle-box can relay then, I think, large numbers of messages might be dropped. Some messages being dropped is fine but most of them should arrive.

How can I address this issue? How can I find out how fast I can send? I want to maintain reasonable packet loss (a few percent) and otherwise maximize bandwidth.

Comment: You will need an ACK- or NACK-based protocol and you will need to use the responses to inform a timing algorithm such as TCP's, and you will ultimately end up with flow control anyway. Too broad.

Comment: Thank you for this question, very rare in the UDP performance discussion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether you will overload the network or not depends on what is between the sender and the receiver hosts. The iperf utility has a UDP option that could help you determine the max rate you could send for a certain level of acceptable packet loss.

That said, from personal experience:
If it's local Gigabit network and client/server on same subnet, I highly doubt you would lose any packets. I've done tests before with iperf in this type of environment and never lost any packets; iperf is going to be one of the fastest and most efficient ways to put UDP packets on to the wire from a PC and we still never lost packets. We were even running the packets through an intel Atom-based Linux host with bridged ports setup while doing tcpdump at the same time and still never lost packets (note that even cheapo switches would perform as good or better than a bridge setup in a PC). The only way we were ever able to get packets to be lost was when we used FPGA/ASIC test devices that could put packets onto the wire at true line-speed for long periods of time. Even at that, the test setup was only losing packets when the packets were less than around 500 bytes.

If you aren't on a local network though (i.e. going over internet or routers) you will just need to do some testing with iperf to see what is acceptable for your environment. Problem is though that what rate can be sustained one day isn't guaranteed to be the same the next day. UDP doesn't have any sort of congestion/flow control algorithms like TCP does so you will have to figure out on your own how fast you can send.